# Pycharm debugger does not work properly on breakpoints

Tags: python, python-3.x, debugging, pycharm, breakpoints

I have code contains many files and many functions.
In Pycharm 2019 IDE, the debugger stop on breakpoints in most of the files correctly, but in some files, the debugger crossed the breakpoints and absolutely deny it.

It should be noted that I checked the running details and I added some print lines near breakpoints and I can see my prints in the console.
In these files, The debugger runs the code instead of debugging!!!
How can I solve this problem?

Comment: share your code where you are having issues while debugging and also share in which code debugging is working fine so it will be clear to understand.

Comment: The code is assigned to me by a company, so I can't share it here (unfortunately)

Answer (score 0):

This could happen for many reasons and impossible to state a direct answer. It's also hard to identify the problem without the relevant code.

Here are some possibilities.

1. An unhandled exception was raised by code long before we ever got to the code containing a breakpoint. That is, the code which gets executed before the code containing a break-point contains an error.
2. The code containing a break-point is ***never*** executed, even when the script runs from start to finish. For example, if the break-point is inside an if-block and the condition of the if-statement is never true, then the breakpoint will never be reached.
3. You are ***not*** running the script you think you are running. Look in the upper right corner of the UI. What is the name of the file next to the run button (green triangle)?
4. Check that thr suspend options are ticked in. Follow these steps: Go to Run->View breakpoints and check if the Suspend option is
   ticked in.

Comment: Are you also using any frameworks, e.g. flask,  pytest, etc. ?

Comment: I checked the items that @AzyCrw4282 said, but none of them didn't happen.
Also I didn't use any frameworks.

Comment: Without the relevant code, it's impossible to identify the error.  I guess then the problem must be to do with your IDE. Try upgrading if possible